# What is the best way to save attachments, DB or local storage?

Tags: java, database

Good afternoon,
i would like to know the best way to save attachments, DB (binary files) or  local storage?

Comment: this question is as old as .. ah nevermind http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525 (edit don't mean to insult anyone by using the word OLD just saying humanity has been pondering about this one for some time)

Comment: This question can't be answered in this form.  What kind of attachments are you saving, and why?

Comment: large images, PDF and others

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  I would use local storage as it's simpler unless you have any specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

For most web based applications, it is typical to store the data on the filesystem and not the database.

The advantage of DB would be single source for backup, and security measures.
The disadvantages would be overhead and connections (some db's charge per connection).

I would personally keep binary data outside of the DB for performance issues alone. Each problem has a unique answer though.